# How to get cursor to move to a Google Sheets row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, selection

I have the following bound script which works to add a new row to a spreadsheet:

```
function addSong() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

What does not work is the last two lines which I expected would place the cursor (i.e., select) the last (and new) line. But it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work," do you mean that it selects the wrong row? Or that it doesn't change the selection at all?

Comment: I mean that the selection does not change. If the cursor is in row 1 or row 20, it stays there after the script runs and adds the new row. I expect the cursor to move into the first cell in the last row and it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try SpreadsheetApp.flush().

```
function addSong() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

This should reset the spreadsheet and make the changes happen right then instead of waiting until the script finishes to add that last row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. You need to use the correct getRange() function that specifies the dimensions of the range; the one that only takes two arguments always returns a single cell.

The program also sets the background colour for clarity on what the range actually is.

This will also set the selection, but you might want to understand the relationship between ranges and the [Selection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)

```
function addSong(song) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1,song]);
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1, 2, 2);

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
  range.setBackground('green');
}

function test() {
  addSong("Stairway to Heaven");
}
```

Comment: Tried both of these methods and a bunch else and again and again, would not work. I finally discovered the reason nothing would work is that the script I kept changing was not actually getting called. Rather, a "gs" script was being invoked and I swear I never added that to the script Project. How it got there, I do not know. Also, I have noticed while working on other scripts that html code pages seem to show up and go away. Any ideas on what this is all about? BTW, thanks much for all of the help. Starting to develop a little bit of comprehension on how all of this works.

Comment: In addition...What I am building is in effect a database to keep track of all of my personal compositions (I'm a songwriter). It is a new Google Site with embedded Google spreadsheets for the song data and Google docs for the lyric sheets.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the Google Scripts editor (Tools >> Script) from the spreadsheet itself? One of the interesting features of the editor is that if you have a function with the same name in different script (.gs) files, e.g. if you have copied a .gs file - it is the newest one that runs, even if you edit the original function. This tripped me up a few times when I first started. 
Which is why I do a lot of my editing offline and synchronize using [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp). Sites/Docs/Sheets does sound like an appropriate tool kit for your app.